# Get Remote Address in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I want to get a remote IP address in angular 4 universal when it renders request on the server side. I tried to get node request object in angular service using zone.js with the following but not to get it,

```
var req = Zone.current.get('req') || {};
var headers = (req && req.headers) ? req.headers : {};
console.log("Zone Headers: " + JSON.stringify(headers));
```

Is there any to get the IP address? I want to pass IP address to the API to get location based results.

How to do it? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass through objects from the express server to the angular app like so...
In your *server.ts* file (which is implementing the express.js server) you have to add a new provider (see 'extraProviders')

```
...
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { 
     document: template
    ,url: options.req.url
    ,extraProviders: [
                         //pass the express.js request object through to the angular4 app
                         { provide: 'request', useFactory: () => options.req }
                     ]
  };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});
...
```

Then in your Angular 4 app you can inject the request object into your service or component like so:

```
import { Injectable, Injector, PLATFORM_ID }  from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';


@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

    constructor(
          private injector: Injector
         ,@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
        ){
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            // -> server rendered
            let requestObj = this.injector.get('request');
            let ip = requestObj.connection.remoteAddress;
        } else {
            // -> browser rendered
        }
    }
...
```

---

Here is my complete *server.ts* file:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';
import * as compression from 'compression';

const PORT = 4200;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { 
     document: template
    ,url: options.req.url
    ,extraProviders: [
                         { provide: 'request', useFactory: () => options.req }
                        ,{ provide: 'host',  useFactory: () => options.req.get('host') }
                     ]
  };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');
app.use(compression());

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```